# How to convert sparse to dense adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, pytorch, adjacency-matrix, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to convert a sparse adjacency matrix/list that only contains the indices of the non-zero elements ([[rows], [columns]]) to a dense matrix that contains 1s at the indices and otherwise 0s. I found a solution using *to_dense_adj* from Pytorch geometric ([Documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.to_dense_adj)). But this does not exactly what I want, since the shape of the dense matrix is not as expected. Here is an example:

```
sparse_adj = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

So the dense matrix should be of size 5x3 (the second array "stores" the columns; with non-zero elements at (0,0), (1,1), (2,2),(1,3) and (0,4)) because the elements in the first array are lower or equal than 2.

However,

```
dense_adj = to_dense(sparse_adj)[0]
```

outputs a dense matrix, but of shape (5,5). Is it possible to define the output shape or is there a different solution to get what I want?

**Edit:** I have a solution to convert it back to the sparse representation now that works

```
dense_adj = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(sparse_adj, torch.ones(5), torch.Size([3,5])).to_dense()
ind = dense_adj.nonzero(as_tuple=False).t().contiguous()
sparse_adj = torch.stack((ind[1], ind[0]), dim=0)
```

Or is there any alternative way that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by first constructing a sparse matrix with [`torch.sparse`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) then converting it to a dense matrix. For this you will need to provide `torch.sparse.FloatTensor` a 2D tensor of indices, a tensor of values as well as a output size:

```
sparse_adj = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
torch.sparse.FloatTensor(sparse_adj, torch.ones(5), torch.Size([3,5])).to_dense()
```

---

You can get the size of the output matrix dynamically with

```
sparse_adj.max(axis=1).values + 1
```

So it becomes:

```
torch.sparse.FloatTensor(
    sparse_adj, 
    torch.ones(sparse_adj.shape[1]), 
    (sparse_adj.max(axis=1).values + 1).tolist())
```

Comment: Is there an appropriate way to convert the dense adjacency matrix back to its sparse representation? I tried it by reshaping and "dense_to_sparse". Unfortunately, the sparse matrix is then [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]] instead of [[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]. I am not sure but I think it is because of the output size. But only changing dimensions does not work.